# How to deal with Image using validated method - Form Request (Laravel 9)

Tags: laravel-9, laravel-formrequest

My form has **4 fields**  `name, email, website and image`

---

When only **`name, email, website`** fields are passed the following code **saves the data** perfectly to my DataBase.

```php
public function store(StoreCompanyRequest $request)
    {
         $validated = $request->validated(); //It will return only validated data
         Company::create($validated); 
     
         return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'message' => 'Company Created Successfully',
        ]);
    }
```

but if the user passes an **`image file`**. The code above saves the image's temporary path.

**This is the output:**

[image]

**Output:** `$validated`

```json
array:4 [  "name" => "infotech"  "email" => "infotech@gmail.iop"  "logo" => Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile {#310  -test: false  -originalName: "greenscreenman.jpg"  -mimeType: "image/jpeg"  -error: 0  #hashName: null  path: "C:\Users\dummy\AppData\Local\Temp"  filename: "php30CD.tmp"  basename: "php30CD.tmp"  pathname: "C:\Users\dummy\AppData\Local\Temp\php30CD.tmp"  extension: "tmp"  realPath: "C:\Users\dummy\AppData\Local\Temp\php30CD.tmp"  aTime: 2022-03-22 12:52:30  mTime:  2022-03-22 12:52:29  cTime: 2022-03-22 12:52:29  inode: 258750  size: 70458  perms: 0100666  owner: 0  group: 0  type: "file"  writable: true  readable: true  executable: false  file: true  dir: false  link: false  linkTarget: "C:\Users\dummy\AppData\Local\Temp\php30CD.tmp"  }  "website" => "www.infotech.com" ]
```

I wrote another code that fixes this problem,

```php
public function store(StoreCompanyRequest $request)
    {
         $validated = $request->validated(); //It will return only validated data
        //  Company::create($validated); 

         $company = new Company;
         $company->name = $validated['name'];
         $company->email = $validated['email'];
         $company->website = $validated['website'];

         $logoName = time().'.'.$request->file('logo')->extension(); 
         $logoPath = $request->file('logo')->storeAs('public/files', $logoName);

         $company->logo = $logoName;
         $company->save();

         return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'message' => 'Company Created Successfully',
        ]);
    }
```

### But is there any way to save the right location of the image with the very first code block???

Comment: The question is a bit unclear.  If you are asking how to "use less lines", well you could start with [the 1-liner shown in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#file-uploads) to store the file, add the resulting `$path` to your `$validated` data, then save.  If you want more control over the details, you'll need "more lines".  If the goal is "less lines" you could extract that part to a separate method ... There are many ways to solve any problem, this is no different.  SO is for help solving specific problems, not opinions on different approaches.

Comment: Hi @Don'tPanic , I have made my question more clear, can you please respond?

Comment: Perform the Image rename/`storeAs()` using the code you have in the 2nd block (`$logoName = time().'.'.$request->file('logo')->extension(); $request->file('logo')->storeAs('public/files', $logoName);`), then call `$validated['logo'] = $logoName;`, then you can call `Company::create($validated);`. Order of operations, and modifying the `$validated` is required if you want to use `::create()` over `->save()`. Note: there is nothing wrong with your second block, other than it being a little more verbose. Again, stackoverflow is not a place for code reviews, but rather help with specific issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there any way to save the right location of the image with the very first code block

No, because the first code block does nothing but validate your input before saving it.  File uploads require some more work.  [The docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#file-uploads) are a good place to start.

Here's what I described in my comment.

If you need some control over the filename:

```php
public function store(StoreCompanyRequest $request)
{
    $validated = $request->validated();

    $path = $request->file('logo')->storeAs(
        'public/files', 
        time() . '.' . $request->file('logo')->extension()
    );

    $validated['logo'] = basename($path);

    Company::create($validated); 

     return response()->json([
        'success' => true,
        'message' => 'Company Created Successfully',
    ]);
}
```

If you don't need control over the filename, you can get Laravel to do a bit more of the work for you:

```php
public function store(StoreCompanyRequest $request)
{
    $validated = $request->validated();

    $path = $request->file('logo')->store('public/files');
    $validated['logo'] = basename($path);

    Company::create($validated); 

     return response()->json([
        'success' => true,
        'message' => 'Company Created Successfully',
    ]);
}
```